# simple parser - why raise `syntax error` when len(tokens) greater than 0?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing

I'm reading up on a simple calculator language interpreter. Posting the whole code here doesn't make sense. Just the section that is relevant as far as I know. In the below function, a `'SyntaxError'` is raised when `len(tokens)` is greater than 0. Which doesn't make sense to me because tokens should always have some length. The second function is the tokenizer function which takes an input expression and generates a tokens list. It can be seen that the length is not zero based on the example. A small glossary is given below -

```
def calc_parse(line):
    """Parse a line of calculator input and return an expression tree."""
    tokens = tokenize(line)
    expression_tree = analyze(tokens)
    if len(tokens) > 0:              #why would length of tokens be 0?
        raise SyntaxError('Extra token(s): ' + ' '.join(tokens))
    return expression_tree

def tokenize(line):
        """Convert a string into a list of tokens."""
        spaced = line.replace('(',' ( ').replace(')',' ) ').replace(',', ' , ')
        return spaced.split()

tokenize('add(2, mul(4, 6))')
#['add', '(', '2', ',', 'mul', '(', '4', ',', '6', ')', ')']

len (tokenize('add(2, mul(4, 6))'))
#11
```

- func `tokenizer` - lexical analyzer
- func `analyze` - syntactic analyzer

where -

> First, the lexical analyzer partitions the input string into tokens,
>   which are the minimal syntactic units of the language, such as names
>   and symbols. Second, the syntactic analyzer constructs an expression
>   tree from this sequence of tokens.

Comment: You don't show the code for `analyze()`, but I would guess that it mutates its argument - ie it removes all the entries from `tokens` as it analyzes them, and if there are any left after it returns that must be a syntax error.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thanks, that's it. I didn't look up the analyze function because it's a page ahead in the text and I was perplexed by this statement. I should have realized that the list was being mutated by `analyze`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman if you can post your comment as an answer, I'll appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment by [DanielRoseman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104349/daniel-roseman) :

The tokens list is being mutated outside the `tokenize` function, using the `analyze`; after which the if condition is good.

> You don't show the code for analyze(), but I would guess that it
>   mutates its argument - ie it removes all the entries from tokens as it
>   analyzes them, and if there are any left after it returns that must be
>   a syntax error. – Daniel Roseman